# Multilanguage wpf application with resources in Visual Studio Designer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-designer

This is my issue:
I have multilanguage WPF application with resources in two different files. Now I choose the proper one in app.xaml.cs like this:

```
var dict = new ResourceDictionary();
switch (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString())
{
    case "de-DE":
        dict.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources;component/StringResources.de-DE.xaml", UriKind.Absolute);
        break;
    default:
        dict.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources;component/StringResources.xaml", UriKind.Absolute);
        break;
}
Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);
```

and everything works fine, but I can't see that resources in VisualStudio Designer.

On the other hand when I define ResourceDictionary in App.xaml file like this:

```
<Application x:Class="Ampe.UI.Views.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Exit="App_OnExit" ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources;component/StringResources.de-DE.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

then I have this resources in designer but I can't set multilanguage.

Is there any possibility to visible resources in designer with multilanguage application? Maybe some kind of change app.xaml file while application is turn on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right way.

1. I'd recommend you to clear application merged dictionaries before adding new ones.

   ```
       Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
       var dict = new ResourceDictionary();
       switch (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString())
       {
           case "de-DE":
               dict.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources;component/StringResources.de-DE.xaml", UriKind.Absolute);
               break;
           default:
               dict.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources;component/StringResources.xaml", UriKind.Absolute);
               break;
       }
       Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);
   ```
2. Your app.xaml should look like you said:

   ```
   <Application x:Class="Ampe.UI.Views.App"

       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       Exit="App_OnExit" ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose">
       <Application.Resources>
           <ResourceDictionary>
               <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                   <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources;component/StringResources.de-DE.xaml"/>
               </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
           </ResourceDictionary>
       </Application.Resources>
   </Application>
   ```
3. When you get localized values from resources, you have to use DynamicResources instead of StaticResources:

   ```
   <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource MyString}" />
   ```

It works for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: it's not working becouse I think that this resources file from app.xaml overwrite this one from app.xaml.cs. I am calling this method before application.Run() and in that method my merged dictionaries is clear. 


Now when I set english culture I have german resources (from app.xaml)

Comment: You could handle application Startup method. It raises after Run method has been called. In Startup handler do exactly the same what you did before Run()

Comment: OK, it's work now, but in designer I always have german resources now. I care to change that depends on culture. Do you know how?

Comment: Ok, your window constructor is called when designer is loaded. You could change your culture in constructor and call the method that replaces ResourceDictionaries. You could do it only in design time with if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)) { /*change culture and replace dictionaries*/} But I don't think it will work. So, the answer is no, you will not be able to change dictionaries at Design Time depending on your culture. You could use WPF Infralution. It's pretty good and meets to your requirements.

Comment: This solution doesn't work and I will check infralution, but thanks for help.

Comment: To me this only worked when I removed the ;component from the source path. So using the OP's code it became like this: <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/StringResources.de-DE.xaml"/>